# n-rooks n-colors problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, latin-square

The problem goes as follows: $n$ colors are used to color the squares in a $n\times m$ chess board so that each color is used exactly $m$ times. Can you always place $n$ rooks on the board, so that the rooks don't attack each other and there is exactly one rook for every color?

Visual example for $8\times 8$:

[image]

What are the values of $n$ and $m$ where this is true? Particularly, what happens when $n=m$? Does this problem have a name? I encountered this problem [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/sdume0/after_several_weeks_study_i_finally_solved_the_8/hugej52/), but the comments were not helpful in my googling attempts.

Obviously, if $n>m$, it's impossible to place $n$ rooks, without them threatening each other. And also if the statement is true for some $(n,m)$ it's also true for $(n,m+1)$.

Here are some colorings that are impossible to satisfy

$$n=m=2$$

\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$$n=m=3$$

\begin{matrix}
2 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$$n=m=4$$

\begin{matrix}
4 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$$n=m=5$$

\begin{matrix}
3 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
5 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: \begin{matrix}1&1&2&2\\2&2&3&3\\3&3&1&1\end{matrix}

Comment: Extension of previous, may provide insight for generalization:\begin{matrix}1&1&1&2&2&2\\2&2&2&3&3&3\\3&3&3&4&4&4\\4&4&4&1&1&1\end{matrix}

Answer (score 3):

## Proof that this is impossible for $n=m$

The proof is disappointingly simple. You can just have every row be numbers $[1,n]$ in order, except the last one which is shifted one down.

Example for $n=4$:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}

The proof that this is impossible is as follows: From the left $n-1$ columns, you will pick every number, except $x$. But because the bottom column is shifted, $x$ will not be on the only open row in the rightmost column. Thus $n=m$ is impossible.

As pointed out by [Daniel Mathias](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/627720/daniel-mathias), this can be easily extended for $n<m\le 2(n-1)$

\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: Simpler proof for the $n \times n$: The last column must contain a rook, and it attacks all squares of some other color.

Answer (score 3):

This is a research area with lots of still-open conjectures.  The seminal paper on this was *Transversals of Latin Squares and their Generalizations* by S. K. Stein ([pdf](https://msp.org/pjm/1975/59-2/pjm-v59-n2-p27-s.pdf)),  Section 4 of this paper contains results such as:

> **Corollary 4.4**: If each symbol in an (m,n)-rectangle appears m times, and if $$n>\frac{m^2-m+2}{2},$$ then there is a latin transversal.

There's 7 conjectures in the final section of this paper, of which 1 and 5 have since been disproved.  (Actually the 5-th conjecture is precisely this question.)

The 5-th conjecture was disproved in *Transversals in Row-Latin Rectangles*, where Drisko (1998) observed it doesn't work for e.g.
$$\begin{array}{|cccccccc|}
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
showing it's not always possible if $n \leq m \leq 2n-2$ (the same as in [AnttiP's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4386254/91818).)

Pokrovskiy and Sudakov (2019; [pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esudakovb/stein-conjecture.pdf)) showed:

> There exists $n \times n$ arrays with every number occurring $n$ times (i.e., equi-$n$-squares) without partial transverals of size $n - \tfrac{1}{42} \ln n$.

Stein's 1-st conjecture was that $n-1$ sufficed, but it turns out that even $n-\text{constant}$ doesn't suffice.